# Can't Spread Array in React (not iterable)

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a fetch and trying to add the contents of a new array to an existing array that is held in state (in a useContext and imported into my component)

```
const [songNames, setSongNames] = useState([]) 


.then((data) => {

let newSongsToAdd = []

data.data.forEach((song) => { 
    ... some logic ...
    newSongsToAdd.push(song)
    }

setSongNames(prevArray => [...prevArray, ...newSongNameArray])
}
```

I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: prevArray is not iterable". I think I've tried every which way, but I can't seem to figure out why the songNames array I have in state is not iterable.

The function otherwise works (I can replace the state, just not spread the new data into it).

Any ideas? Full error below, thanks!

```
Uncaught TypeError: prevArray is not iterable
    at HomePage.js:145:1
    at basicStateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16540:1)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16664:1)
    at updateState (react-dom.development.js:17004:1)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17915:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at Provider (Context.js:19:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
```

Comment: `setSongNames([...songNames, ...newSongNameArray])`, try this.

Comment: still receive : TypeError: songNames is not iterable
    at HomePage.js:145:1

Comment: Could you add more code of the `HomePage.js`